# OpenCV Java SimpleBlobDetector does not detect any Keypoints

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, android

I am new to OpenCV and I use [this repo](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/opencv-android) to import OpenCV Java into my project.

I imported the latest version there `4.3.0` and I want to try Blob Detection feature but cannot.

I found SimpleBlobDetector class which does not have a way to pass Params to it or any other way to pass filters. So I was only able to code the following:

```
private fun Mat.simpleBlobDetectDraw(): Mat {
    val mat = Mat()
    val sbd = SimpleBlobDetector.create()
    val keyPoints = MatOfKeyPoint()
    sbd.detect(this, keyPoints)
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(this, keyPoints, mat, randomColorScalar(), Features2d.DrawMatchesFlags_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
    return mat
}
```

But when I run this, nothing happens, no keyPoints are found. So I don't know which direction to go. I have suspect that openCV Java library does not have complete API for Blob detection, is that true?

Googling about this issue didn't give any useful information either.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth looking at the simple blob detector examples in more detail to get a proper feel for how they work, but at a high level you need to tell it which color to detect and it will then find the contours or outline lines for any shapes or blobs that are made up of that color.

The steps the detector takes are:

- reduce the size of the image
- filter out everything that is not the color we are looking for
- enhance the remaining parts of the image to make it easier to detect edges or contours
- find the contours (the outline or the edge) of the remaining 'blobs' of color
- filter out any that are too small to be of interest
- return the list of remaining blobs, or more accurately the list of contours which are the outline of the remaining blobs

This answer contains a detailed commented code extract to explain the steps more fully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40918718/334402